# SQL Server Pass Variable to stdevp

Tags: sql-server

How can I use the `stdevp` function with the addition of a parameter from a previous calculation?  Lets say I have a previous step which calculates an average.

```
declare @Average float;
select @Average = ... some calculation
```

I then want to use that number for each row when calculating the standard deviation.

So I have a table

```
Id, SomeNumber
0, 1.2
1, 3.5
2, 5.6
...
```

How can I use the `@Average` variable when along with the `stdevp` and `SomeNumber` column?  I was initially thinking about inserting a `@Average` row for every "regular" row into a temp table, but I'm wondering if there's a simpler option which doesn't require me to insert values into a temp table.

```
-- Temp table
Id, SomeNumber
0, 1.2
0, 3.4333
1, 3.5
1, 3.4333
2, 5.6
2, 3.4333

select Id, stdevp(SomeNumber)
from #MyTempTable
group by Id
```

Comment: You can try this: `select Id, stdevp(SomeNumber+@Average )
from #MyTempTable
group by Id`

Comment: @МаксимЗолотенко that causes every result to be `0` because only one record is used for the stdev calculation.

Comment: `select Id,
  stdevp(SomeNumber)
from (
   select id,
     SomeNumber
   from #MyTempTable
   union all
   select id,
     @Average
   from #MyTempTable
  ) v1
group by Id`